# Integral dependence and rings of fractions

Tags: commutative-algebra

I have a question on a Proposition in Atiyah and MacDonald's text. It concerns Proposition 5.12 ($A$ and $B$ are commutative rings with an identity) pictured here:

[image]

Here's my concern: After multiplying the equation of integral dependence in the ring of fractions through by $(st)^n$ we'll obtain something of the form

$$\frac{ (bt)^n + a_1'(bt)^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n'}{1}=0$$

in $S^{-1}B$ where $a_i'\in A$ ($1\leq i \leq n$). Thus we conclude there exists $u\in S$ such that

$$u\left[(bt)^n + a_1'(bt)^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n'\right]=0.$$

If $B$ were an integral domain (and $0 \notin S$), then we arrive at the desired equation of integral dependence for $bt$ over $A$. But $B$ is assumed arbitrary---we might have zero-divisors. Am I missing something? How do we obtain their conclusion without the assumption that $B$ is an integral domain?

You can see the title of the section, so maybe this was a missing hypothesis...?

Comment: If you have $0$ in $S$ then $S^{-1}B = 0$. I'm not sure why you want $B$ to be an integral domain. If some of the terms become zero after multiplying with $u$ then it is still an equation of integral dependence in $bt$.

Comment: It's not though, since the polynomial for which $bt$ is a root is not monic; it has leading coefficient equal to $u$. As I understand the definitions, this is not an algebraic dependence that we're after.

Comment: Any chance this is a hypothesis in 5.6(ii) that is carried over?

Comment: 5.6 begins with, "Let $A\subseteq B$ be rings, $B$ integral over $A$." Part (ii) then says, "If $S$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $A$, then $S^{-1}B$ is integral over $S^{-1}A$." That was one of the first things I checked.

Comment: Actually, in Matsumura Commutative Algebra this is example 3 p.65, and again there is no mention that $B$ is a domain.

Comment: @JohnM Oh you are right, looking at Kato-san's answer makes it quite clear. +1. I guess when I get up in the morning I should drink coffee first, before looking at SE : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$u\left[(bt)^n + a_1'(bt)^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n'\right]=0.$

Multiplying the both sides by $u^{n-1}$, we get

$(ubt)^n + ua_1'(ubt)^{n-1} + \cdots + u^na_n'=0.$

Hence $ubt \in C$.
Therefore $b/s = ubt/stu \in S^{-1}C$.

Comment: Good! Thank you very much!